# Что делать, если тэг <input...> не содержит атрибута name

Tags: python, requests

Есть страничка на сайте, где задаётся диапазон дат "от" и "до":

```
                <h2 class="b-part-header b-part-header_date"><i></i>Дата регистрации дела</h2>
                <div class="b-selected-tags g-ec" id="sug-dates">
                    <label class="from">
                        <strong>с</strong>
                        <input class="anyway_position_top" type="text" value="" placeholder="дд.мм.гггг" />
                    </label>
                    <label class="to">
                        <strong>по</strong>
                        <input class="anyway_position_top" type="text" value="" placeholder="дд.мм.гггг" />
                    </label>
                </div>
```

Имеется два тэга <input...> у которых нет атрибута `name` или `id`.
Пишу программу на питоне, которая использует библиотеку `requests`.

Вопрос: Как написать вызов *requets.get(...)*, что бы задать диапазон дат ?

Вот что я вижу на закладке "Сеть" отладчика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем вам атрибут name или id у input-a для GET запроса? 
Скорее всего при выборе дат у вас в адресной появляется что-то вроде такого: http://site.com/products?dateFrom=....&dateTo=...
соответственно в requests.get и нужно передать этот запрос

Comment: Сделайте в браузер запрос и посмотрите в инспекторе на вкладке сетей какой запрос отправился и повторите его. Если непонятно как запрос повторить, то приложите его в вопрос. Или дайте ссылку на страницу с инструкцией :)

Comment: @gil9red "Сделайте в браузер запрос и посмотрите в инспекторе на вкладке сетей" я не знаю, как это сделать. У меня браузер - хром. Я открываю некое окошко, которое называется "Дополнительные инструменты разработчика". Там куча закладок и одна называется "Сеть". Но там ни фига нет. Только какой-то профайлер с осью времени...  Там есть **счётчик** запросов и видно, как он увеличивается, когда я нажимаю кнопку *Submit*. Но самих запросов не вижу...

Comment: Может у вас не все типы запросов выбраны или в поле Filter что-то набрано? Должны именно в Network все запросы отображаться

Comment: Изменил основной вопрос, что бы показать, что я вижу в отладчике.

Comment: Я так понимаю, вопрос у вас больше по тому как пользоваться средствами отладки. Ниже профайлера, отображается список запросов, но он у вас пустой, надо обновить страницу, к тому же установлен какой то фильтр.

Comment: @Максим - "список запросов,  у вас пустой" Да и я не понимаю, почему. Когда я нажимаю "Обновить", счётчик запросов увеличивается.  Но в окошке ничего нет. "установлен какой то фильтр"  Да и я не могу его очистить. Даже доку искать не хочется, так как предполагаю, что там 5000 страниц будет :-(

Comment: "Есть страничка на сайте" адрес предоставите?

Comment: @СергейШашко - "адрес предоставите?"   - Спасибо, я уже разобрался с проблемой. Так что дело не в адресе было, а в том, что у меня был включен фильтр сообщений. Я отключил фильтр, посмотрел запрос PUT, который отправляет браузер и увидел у него в поле *Payload* идентификаторы переменных, которые меня интересовали.